# Maven project middleware dependency upgrade

Tags: spring, maven, java-8, overlay

I have a project that utilizes the following architecture:

MIDDLEWARE

APPLICATION

CUSTOMIZED APPLICATION

The build environment utilizes what is known as a `maven-overlay`.
The Application contains references to the Middleware dependencies, so those get installed into my maven repo when I build the Application.
Next, when I build my Customized Application, I reference the Application as a dependency - my customizations get overlayed on top of the Application classes.
The final product that is created is war file that I deploy on a Tomcat webserver after building my Customized Application.

The overall project is getting pretty old - the Middleware was developed back in the 2011/2012 so it's using outdated versions of ... well everything!

The Middleware and Application use an old version of Spring (3.1.0) and were originally developed using JDK 6.  Several years back I moved to JDK 7.  However, recently I tried building and deploying my customized application using JDK11 - but ran into all kinds of issues, so I throttled back to JDK8; but, even with JDK8 there is an issue.  Specifically it has to do with Lamba expressions and some other nuances that my current version of Spring (3.1.0) doesn't know how to handle.  That being said - the solution is to update the version of Spring that the Middleware is using so that the overall project can utilize JDK8 (for TLS1.2, beefer security, etc.)

Question:  How do I update a dependency in my Middleware?
I've looked at the Middleware source code (so I do have access to the source code if necessary) and I see this dependency in the main POM of the project:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

Again - I need to update this version to 4.0.0.M1 to solve my problem, but I'm not sure how to do that given the build environment that I described above, where the APPLICATION pulls in that Middleware dependency (which in turn is the one that pulls in that old spring version).

Thanks.

Comment: The first thing I would do to upgrade all plugins in your Maven build and of course Maven itself to the most recent version. Then get your build running with JDK8.  Than you should upgrade your spring version to 3.1.0 to 4. and after wards to 5.X if that's all done go to JDK 11 cause I bet you will find other issues. I hope you have a good test suite...?

Answer (score 0):

So, long story short on this one is that in order to affect the dependency that is being managed by the middleware - I needed to upgrade the middleware to the appropriate version that would solve my JDK problem but at the same time jive with my application's architecture (e.g. I couldn't just automatically take the latest middleware version as much as I would have liked, so I took the highest version possible and solved both problems after A LOT of work.

Ended up going with JDK8 + a version of the middleware that used Spring version 3.2.3.  This Spring version allows to target JDK 1.7 byte code but build using 1.8 JDK.